# Implementing class for pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

For example,

```
val list = List(1,2,3)
list match {
  case a :: b => 
  case _      => 
}
```

you can match head and tail of a List using `::` or tokens of ParseResult using `~`. What should I do to create class that can be matched like preceding classes?

UPD:

And have possibility to write:

```
case class @ ...
List(1,2,3,4) match {
  case 1 @ 2 @ 3 @ 4 => 
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `::` instead of `:::`

Comment: For your `@` example, you can write that with `::` instead: `case 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: Nil => ...`.

Comment: @absz the question is how to create classes like ::

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's not much to it. These two statements are equivalent:

```
case x :: xs =>
case ::(x, xs) =>
```

Say you want something to separate a list into odds and evens, and call it `**`. You could write the extractor like this:

```
object ** {
  def unapply(xs: List[Int]) = Some(xs partition (_ % 2 == 0))
}

scala> List(1,2,3) match {
     |   case evens ** odds => println("Evens: "+evens+"\nOdds: "+odds)
     | }
Evens: List(2)
Odds: List(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you define your class as a [case class](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/107) it can be pattern-matched like this.

If you want to pattern-match on something other than the class's constructor, you can use [extractors](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112) to define custom patterns.